# Ajax Login form gets submitted even if info is invalid

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I have called the validate function onclick for the submit button. 
HTML

```
<form role="form" style="margin:0 20px 0 0; float:right" method="post" action="login.php" id="loginform">
    <h3>Login</h3>
    <div class="form-group" >
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter username" name='username' id="username_input">
        <label >Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control"  placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password_input">
    </div>
    <div id="login_feedback"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="validate()"></input><br/>   
</form>
```

JS

The form gets submitted always. I want to submit only when responseText is "correct"

```
 function validate() {
   var xhr;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else {
        throw new Error("Ajax is not supported by this browser");
    }
    var username = document.getElementById("username_input").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password_input").value;
    xhr.open('POST', 'validate.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("username=" + username + "&password=" + password );    
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            var data=xhr.responseText.trim();
            document.getElementById("login_feedback").innerHTML = data;
            if (data=='correct'){
                     document.getElementById("loginform").submit();
                }
    } 
    return false;
    )

}
```

Comment: What does validate.php look like? Maybe the error is in that file?

Comment: I guess your form is getting submitted due to the default action of the submit button. Can you try adding `onsubmit="return false;"` to the form tag?

Comment: `onclick="return validate()"` ?

Comment: besides the two valid points above.. what's that closing parenthesis right after `return false`? is that just a typo or you have it in your source?

Comment: even if this is not the question I find it strange that you are capturing the event on the form with the id `loginform` and in certain conditions you are triggering the submit event on that same form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.It is working. The reason it didn't work is because you were not checking the status and readystate of the ajax request.

```
function validate() {

   var xhr;
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else {
        throw new Error("Ajax is not supported by this browser");
    }

    var username = document.getElementById("username_input").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password_input").value;
    xhr.open('POST', 'validate.php',true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("username=" + username + "&password=" + password );   
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
 if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)   //this is needed
    {
    var data=xhr.responseText.trim();
            document.getElementById("login_feedback").innerHTML = data;
            if (data=='correct'){
                     document.getElementById("loginform").submit();
                }
    }

    } 
   }
```

Hope this helps, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

your not validating anything in your `validate` function. at least add a basic check as follows to see if the variables are empty or not.

```
var username = document.getElementById("username_input").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password_input").value;
if (username.trim() == "" || password.trim() == "") return false;
```