# I'm trying to send username and password to a php file using AJAX with post method. How to retrieve fields

Tags: php, html, ajax

How to access these variables ?
I'm trying to retrieve username and password in php files, But, it says Undefined index username if I use `$_POST['Username'}`

```
 <script>
    var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
    a.onreadystatechange = function(){
         if (a.readyState==4 && a.status==200) {
              ajaxFinished = true; 
              alert(a.responseText);
         }
         else {
         }                          
    }
    a.open("post","php/psswd.php",true);
    a.send('"Username="+document.getElementByNames("Username")+"&Password="+getElementByNames("Password")'); // posting username and password
 </script>
```

How to retrieve these fields in php file ?

Comment: It should be `$_POST['Username']` why are you using `}` ?

Comment: Try removing the single quotes at `a.send`.

Comment: Im sorry, typo error, I'm using $_POST['Username'] only

Comment: Thanks Dave, but nothing changed.

Comment: Sidenote: In relying on POST variables from a form, variables are case-sensitive, should this be the case. `Username` and `username` are two different animals altogether.

Comment: but they are correct, names are proper.

Comment: It might have something to do in your PHP then. Is there something to the effect of `$Username=$_POST['Username];` in there? You're only mentioning that you're using `$_POST['Username']` but no variable.

Comment: $encrypted_text = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_DES, $_POST["Username"], $_POST["Password"], MCRYPT_ENCRYPT); this is how i retrieve

Comment: The syntax is `getElementByName` and not in the plural form that you have `getElementByNames` try that now. @user3413403

Comment: So, I take it it's working then.

Comment: I made a slight mistake, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the answer myself, the problem was that,
   a.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
needs to be added. And document.getElementsByName('xyz') returns nodeList, but not perticular node, We need to traverse that nodeList.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is `getElementsByName` and not the way you presently have `getElementByNames`

The word Elements is pluralized, not Names.

```
<script>
    var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
    a.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (a.readyState==4 && a.status==200)
            {
            ajaxFinished = true; 
            alert(a.responseText);
            }
        else
            {

            }

        }
        a.open("post","php/psswd.php",true);
        a.send('"Username="+document.getElementsByName("Username")+"&Password="+getElementsByName("Password")'); // posting username and password
</script>
```

For more information on this, visit:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName

---

### Edit

The following works using jQuery and tested with FF 28.0 and IE 7.

Sidenote: You may want to change this `window.location = "success.php"`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
function chk_ajax_login_with_php(){
  var username=document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password=document.getElementById("password").value;

    var params = "username="+username+"&password="+password;
    var url = "php/psswd.php";
        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: url,
           dataType: 'html',
           data: params,
           beforeSend: function() {
             document.getElementById("status").innerHTML= 'checking...'  ;
                     },
           complete: function() {

           },
           success: function(html) {

                 document.getElementById("status").innerHTML= html;
                 if(html=="success"){

                   window.location = "success.php"

                 }

            }
   });

}
</script>


</head>


<body>
<div id='logindiv'>

    <label>Username:</label>
        <input name="username" id="username" type="text">
    <label>Password:</label>
        <input name="password" id="password" type="password">
        <input value="Submit" name="submit" class="submit" type="submit" onclick='chk_ajax_login_with_php();'>
    <div id='status'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No i have changed it to document.getElementsByName , still not working

Comment: One more question, How to wait for the response ?

Comment: Which response is that? @user3413403

Comment: I'm still getting Unidentified index Username as error message

Comment: I've got both eyes in the same socket, it's passed 2am here and I can't think straight enough to keep going. If nobody else gives an answer, I'll help out tomorrow morning. In the meantime [`see this answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18270678/) on SO, it may help if you can look at that. @user3413403

Comment: Plus, if you can post your PHP in your question, that will help also. @user3413403

Comment: See my **Edit** it works with jQuery. I'll contact you tomorrow. @user3413403

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the XMLHttpRequest method, take a look at this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#loginForm').submit(function(e) {
            var username    = $("#login-username").val(); //id of the form text input
                password    = $("#login-password").val(); //id of the form text input

             e.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: url,
             data: { form: 'login', username: '' + username + '', password: '' + password + ''}
           }).success(function( msg ) {
             //msg is the text returned from the PHP function that will validate the login
               $('.login_success_text').html(msg);
          });
        });
</script>

<body>

               <form role="form" name="loginForm" id="loginForm" method="POST">
                  <label>Username</label>
                  <input id="login-username" class="form-control text placeholder" placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text">
                  <label>Password</label>
                  <input id="login-password" class="form-control password placeholder" placeholder="Password" name="password" autocomplete="off" type="password">
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
                <div class="login_success">
                  <span class="login_success_text"></span>
                </div>
</body>
```